# Lag in Kubuntu - Config fstab correctly?

Tags: mount, kubuntu, fstab

I use Kubuntu and have a partition with NTFS format which contain old data from previous version Ubuntu. I configured fstab to mount it:

```
/dev/sda6  /home/stun  ntfs    permissions,uid=1000        0     2
```

Then my OS run very laggy, I found the `mount.ntfs` run frequently. It might consume 30 ~ 40% CPU.

Please give an advice to solve this, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the partition to ext4; if your system is all Ubuntu there is no reason to put up with the overhead associated with using an ntfs file system.  Here are the steps I went through to convert mine.

> 1) copy data from original partition
>
> 2) gparted: unmount partition
>
> 3) gparted: format to ext4
>
> 4) gparted: label the partition
>
> 5) copy the new UUID from gparted and edit fstab
>
> 6) `sudo mount -a` to test mounting it
>
> 7) check permissions on mount point are `drwxrwxrwx`
>
> 8) copy data back

Comment: but i'm using dual boot ( Kubuntu and Windows 10), is there any other idea?

Comment: I am sorry, you did not mention Windows in your question, only Ubuntu and Kubuntu, so this is not the best answer for you. I hope someone will post a better one for your setup.